# jquery JqGrid Output Layout error

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jqgrid, couchdb

i have made a simple HTML Form. I want to grab some JSON data out of a CouchDB and display it in jqGrid. But all i get is this sh**** Output in Firefox or IE. [Output Firefox](http://i62.tinypic.com/ftio87.png)
It's just one row but i don't know why the list gets so long. I also dont know why some parts are pulled apart (sorry i cant speak good english).

This is how it looks before i start the javascript action and i made a simple red box indicatting where the jqGrid should be: [HTML Page before Action](http://i57.tinypic.com/2pzcs4y.png)
As you can see, my two textboxes get covered by the jqGrid.

I dont know what causes this Problem and i don't have enough Knowledge of all this. Can someone help me ?

Here is my Code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Testformular</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="/DataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="jqgrid/js/minified/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script src="jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-de.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqgrid/js/minified/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqgrid/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqgrid/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqgrid/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.structure.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqgrid/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.theme.css">
<!--
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.pager.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.edit.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/scripts/demos.js"></script>
-->




<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<script src="index2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body  onLoad="inputonload();">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="eingabe">
            <form name="form" method="post">        
                        <div>
                            <input class="input" onmouseover="clearOnClickFromkkz()" onmouseout="test()" value="Kundenkürzel" type="text" id="kkz">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input class="input" onmouseover="clearOnClickFrommgr()" onmouseout="manager_updat()" type="text" id="mgr" name="manager" value="Manager">
                        </div>
                    </form>
        </div>
        <table id="Grid1" style="height: 290px; width: 444px"><div id="gridpager"></div></table>

        </div>              
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My Javascript File

```
function clearOnClickFromkkz() {
    if (document.getElementById('kkz').value === "Kundenkürzel") {
        document.getElementById('kkz').value = "";
        document.getElementById('kkz').style.color = "#000000";
    }
}
function clearOnClickFrommgr() {
    if (document.getElementById('mgr').value === "Manager") {
        document.getElementById('mgr').value = "";
        document.getElementById('mgr').style.color = "#000000";
    }
}
function inputonload() {
    document.getElementById('kkz').style.color = "#A1A1A1";
    document.getElementById('mgr').style.color = "#A1A1A1";
}

function manager_updat() {
    var link = 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/php_couch3/_design/mgr/_view/by_mgr?key="' + document.getElementById('mgr').value + '"';
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: link,
        dataType: "json",
    });
    request.done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $("#content").html(data);
    });
    if (document.getElementById('mgr').value === "") {
        document.getElementById('mgr').value = "Manager";
        document.getElementById('mgr').style.color = "#A1A1A1";
    }
}
function sid_update() {
    var link = 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/php_couch3/_design/sid/_view/by_sid?key="' + document.getElementById('kkz').value + '"';
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: link,
        dataType: "json",
    });
    request.done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $("#content").html(data);
    });
    if (document.getElementById('kkz').value === "") {
        document.getElementById('kkz').value = "Kundenkürzel";
        document.getElementById('kkz').style.color = "#A1A1A1";
    }

}
function test() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var pager = '#gridpager';
        jQuery("#Grid1").jqGrid({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/php_couch3/_design/sid/_view/by_sid?key="' + document.getElementById('kkz').value + '"',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['key', 'value'],
            colModel: [{ name: 'key', index: 'key', width: 150 },
                       { name: 'value', index: 'value', width: 150}],
            sortname: 'id',
            pager: '#gridpager',
            viewrecoreds: true,
            scrollOffset: 0,
            imgpath: 'Themes/images'
        }).navGrid(pager, {edit: true, add: true, del: true, refresh: true, search: true, position: 'left'});
    });
}
```

And my CSS File:

```
body{

}
.input {
    margin:0px;
    font-size:12px;
    width:90%;
    height:30px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle
}
div.eingabe {
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
div.content {
    border:1px solid #efeff7;
    background-color:#efeff7;
    width:650px;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
}
div.page {
    position:absolute;
    width:805px;
    height:90%;
    min-height:600px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-top:10px;
    border: 0px lime solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check that you are getting data. Use the dev console in FF/Chrome/IE you access it with F12, you can see the network tab and check your requests and responses.
Also there you can see any errors on the javascript code, check the console output

Comment: Heyy, i got it !!! I had to change some settings in the CSS File of the jqGrid Plugin. The Option "overflow-x:hidden" solved my Problems. I had to add it into the class ".ui-jqgrid" in the File "ui.jqgrid.css". @manhatten Thank You for your Help, but i got it solved!!